# worksheet_change Event Not Firing WIth Data Validation

Tags: validation, events

I want to call methods in module from Worsheet_Change. It does work when i modifiy directly a cell bus it seems to exit Worsheet_Change when i select data from validation list.

Exemple : This Works
Debug.Print Now & " - SESSION_06 : Worksheet_Change " & Target.Address
MonChange Target ' a method within the worksheet
Debug.Print Now & " - SESSION_06 : Worksheet_Change FIN " & Target.Address

Exemple : This doesn't Works with data validation, it seems to exist after the first line and no brek point will work, but it works fine with direct edit of a cell
Debug.Print Now & " - SESSION_06 : Worksheet_Change " & Target.Address
Session_Change_6 Target ' a method in a module
Debug.Print Now & " - SESSION_06 : Worksheet_Change FIN " & Target.Address

It's like it's not able to execute module code and doesn't show any error when i select a data in the validation list...

I verified that events are activated, that there is no protection on the worksheet